# Trying to import data and classes from NON React script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, architecture, export

I'm trying to make a card game with React. I made a script that exports a Deck Class, and I want to import it into the React component that holds the field. However, it won't let me import a non-React file into a React Component. How can I get these files to communicate, or is there a different code architecture I should be using?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the script exports the class? Do you mean a file exporting the class?

Comment: Please post your code so we may help you.

Comment: Here's the link to the GitHub Repo where it's stored https://github.com/KilometersDodecahedron/card-game

Comment: Yes, I mean a file exporting a class. More specifically, I'm making a Card Game with React, I have a "Deck" class, and I want to import it into the "Field" react component